Was there an "understanding between King Abdullah and the Jewish Agency to partition Palestine between themselves"?
According to Avi Shlaim's "The Debate about 1948", p. 293

If Bevin was guilty of conspiring to unleash the Arab Legion, his target was not
the Jews but the Palestinians. The prospect of a Palestinian state was pretty remote
in any case because the Palestinians themselves had done so little to build it. But
by supporting Abdullah's bid to capture the Arab part of Palestine adjacent to his
kingdom, Bevin indirectly helped to ensure that the Palestinian state envisaged in
the U.N. partition plan would be stillborn. In short, if there is a case to be made
against Bevin, it is not that he tried to abort the birth of the Jewish state but that he
endorsed the understanding between King Abdullah and the Jewish Agency to partition Palestine between themselves and leave the Palestinians out in the cold.
The Zionist charge that Bevin deliberately instigated hostilities in Palestine and
gave encouragement and arms to the Arabs to crush the infant Jewish state thus represents almost the exact opposite of the historical truth as it emerges from the British, Arab, and Israeli documents. The charge is without substance and may be safely
discarded as the first in the series of myths that have come to surround the founding
of the State of Israel.

The passage doesn't footnote any materials though.
So, what evidence is there of a conspiracy/agreement between the Jewish Agency and King Abdullah for the latter to take over the West Bank etc. in 1948?

I see Wikipedia has a short para about this, which isn't terribly detailed "According to Yoav Gelber, Shlaim's claim that there was a deliberate and pre-meditated anti-Palestinian "collusion" between the Jewish Agency and King Abdullah, is unequivocally refuted by the documentary evidence on the development of contacts between Israel and Jordan before, during and after the war.[19] Marc Lynch however wrote that "the voluminous evidence in [Gelber's] book does not allow so conclusive a verdict".[20]"

Not an answer but Prof. Shlaim speaks about it  here too https://www.meforum.org/92/a-totalitarian-concept-of-history; he says there was a meeting between Golda Meir and King `Abdallah of Transjordan on November 17, 1947

Morris also writes about it in page 191 of History of The First Arab Israeli War. He cites:  Ezra Danin, “Conversation with 'Abdullah 17. 11.47,” undated, CZAS25-4004; Golda Meir, protocol of meeting of People’s Administration, 12 May 1948, ISA, People’s Administration, 40.

I'm not even understanding the claim here. Is the book saying that fledgling Israel incited the Arab nations to attack non-Israeli Palestine to destroy the Palestinians? So how come they actually ended up fighting Israel?

@DJClayworth The claim is the Jordanian king betrayed the Palestinains by making a secret deal With the zionist leadership (later Israel) to split the land. Supposedly, The goal of the Jordanian participation in the 1948 war was not to fight Israel but to expand Jordan's territory

Seems like a better question for History.SE.

@Ona Sounds very far-fetched given the actual fighting that happened. Are we saying that the large numbers of Jews killed in the Battle of Latrun was by agreement with the Israelis?

In 1921 Britain created Trans-Jordan and gave it to the
Hashemites to rule over. Trans-Jordan is an arbitrary piece of
the Arabian desert and Churchill famously boasted that he had created
it with "a stroke of his pen" on a Sunday afternoon. Syria
considered Jordan to be part of Southern Syria. Ibn Saud, king
of Saudi Arabia, considered the territory part of his kingdom. On
the other hand, the Hashemite king Abdullah made no secret of his
plans to expand his kingdom. Hence, Trans-Jordan's standing on the
international scene was precarious and greater cooperation with the
Zionists in Palestine became logical.
King Abdullah and Golda Meir of the Jewish Agency had a secret meeting
in the middle of November 1947. There, they outlined a general
strategy for the upcoming war in Palestine that they both knew were
inevitable. A few days later the UN General Assembly would recommend
that Palestine be partitioned into a Jewish and an Arab state, against
the wishes of its population. According to Yaacov Shimoni of the
Jewish Agency, who Shlaim cites:

We would agree to the conquest of the Arab part of Palestine by
Abdullah. We would not stand in his way. We would not help him,
would not seize it and hand it over to him. He would have to take it
by his own means and stratagems but we would not disturb him. He,
for his part, would not prevent us from establishing the state of
Israel, from dividing the country, taking our share and establishing
a state in it.

Meir and Abdullah met again in May 1948, days before Israel
declared independence. There he lamented the circumstances that forced
his hand, "I am one among five. I have no alternative [but to declare
war], and I cannot act otherwise" Meir reported back to the Mapai
Central Committee:

We met [on 10 May] amicably. He is very worried and looks
terrible. He did not deny that there had been talk and understanding
between us about a desirable arrangement, namely that he would take
the Arab part [of Palestine]...."

But the agreement with the Zionists held; his Arab Legion would not
enter territory earmarked for the Jewish State.
The supreme commander of the Arab Legion was Glubb Pasha, a British
officer tasked with implementing the Jordanian part of the
agreement. He discussed the parties' plans for Palestine in a meeting
with the British Foreign Secretary, Ernest Bevin, in London in
February 1948:

The situation envisaged by us and by H.M.G. when we were in London,
was that nothing much would happen until May 15th. The Jews would
then implement the Jewish state, with the blessing of a united
U.N.O., and the Arab areas of Palestine would be a vacuum, into
which the Arab Legion would march.

Throughout the war the alliance mostly held; the Arab Legion and the
Haganah/IDF avoided battling each other. Jerusalem which had been
allotted to an international zone was the major exception. Glubb
suspected that the Zionists would certainly try to capture the whole
city for themselves. Abdullah was also subjected to repeated pleas to
save the Arabs of Palestine. Thus, he ordered Glubb to take the Arab
Legion into Jerusalem and Glubb reluctantly accepted. However,
the Arab Legion only occupied the Old City and Arab parts of Jerusalem - the Jewish colony in west Jerusalem was left alone.
Counterpoint Israeli and Jordanian units fought each other so
there couldn't have been an alliance.
This a bogus argument since by the same logic the Molotov-Ribbentrop
Pact couldn't have existed since the heaviest fighting of the
Second World War was on the eastern front between the Germans and the
Soviets. Tactical considerations, fog of war, politics, and other
factors explain perfectly well why Israeli and Jordanian units clashed despite the agreement.

There was no "alliance". The harshest fighting of the war took place between Jordanian and Israeli forces in the area between Tel Aviv and Jerusalem.

The addendum about the Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact seems a bit off: Germany explicitly broke that alliance, leading Russia to switch sides in the larger war. That doesn't seem a relevant comparison in this case, where you're arguing that the alliance "mostly held" throughout the war.

Operation Barbarossa does not disprove the Molotov-Ribbentrop Pact. Hence fighting between Jewish and Jordanian troops does not disprove the Hashemite-Zionist agreement. The claim that it "mostly held" comes from the scholarly sources I cite. According to them the cooperation continued up until Abdullah's assassination in 1951.

My point is that it's a poor analogy, unless you are claiming that the Hashenite-Zionist alliance was similarly broken by unambiguous aggression by one or other party. Operation Barbarossa was about as far as you can get from "fog of war, politics, and other factors". Note that I'm not arguing with your actual claim that an agreement of sorts need not preclude all fighting; I'm just arguing that this analogy does nothing to support that claim. "Alliances can be broken, hence, alliances can coexist with fighting" is a non sequitur.
